# Can we extract thumbnails embedded in TIFF files with metadata-extractor?

Tags: metadata-extractor

I'm able to use ExifTool to extract an embedded thumbnail jpeg from within a TIFF.  Is there a way that I can do this with drew noakes' metadata-extractor?

The source file is here:
https://corpora.tika.apache.org/base/docs/commoncrawl3/RD/RDAFESH5CBBJWWQZMZR4MGJIPYYEL7DN

The extracted thumbnail/preview image is [image: here].

I see the 5225 byte count in a metadata item (0x0202) with metadata-extractor, but I'm not able to get the bytes.

Thank you!